# Confused by use of Cauchy Binet formula

Tags: matrices, determinant

This is taken from the article here:

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087.1982.11882087

Given a matrix $$C = \mathrm{diag}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n) + V\,\mathrm{diag}(\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n)V^*$$

where $V$ is an $n\times n$ unitary matrix.

The author uses the Cauchy-Binet formula to obtain
\begin{gather}
\det C = \\
\sum_{t=0}^{n} \sum_{1\le j_1 \lt...\lt j_{n-t} \le n} \sum_{1\le k_1 \lt...\lt k_{t} \le n} \Big|\det V[i_1,i_2,...,i_t|k_1,k_2,...k_t]\Big|^2\alpha_{j_1}\alpha_{j_2}...\alpha_{j_{n-t}}\beta_{k_1}\beta_{k_2}...\beta_{k_t}
\end{gather}

where $\{j_1,...j_{n-t}\}$ and $\{i_1,...i_t\}$ are complementary in $\{1,2,...,n\}$

I don't see how the author is getting this result. The Cauchy Binet formula concerns the product of two matrices... so which two matrices are being used to apply the Cauchy Binet formula? Can someone break this down for me in steps? Thanks.

Comment: What he is using are two classical determinant identities: Corollary 5.161 and Corollary 7.150 in [Darij Grinberg, *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 26 April 2018](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2018-04-26) for example. The first one serves to rewrite the determinant as a sum of products of $\alpha_j$'s times principal minors of the second matrix; the second one then computes the latter minors. The second one is an easy corollary of Cauchy-Binet, so I can see why the author is citing Cauchy-Binet.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out those notes!